# 404 custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I've set up some custom post types and wanted to visit the pages but I only get 404 errors.

I've searched the web and it seems to be a known problem, but I didn't find a solution that worked for me.

I saved the permalinks several times and also tried the `flush_rewrite_rules( false );` command on every post type. But nothing changes.

If I set the permalink structure to basic, everything works fine, so the post types are ok...

Can anyone think of another problem?

Maybe it's because I used the same permalink for a page (`post_type => 'page`)? But I've deleted that page and I cannot find anything else than my page of the custom post type with that title in the database. So everything should be fine.

---

The `$args`:

```
$args = array(
    'labels'              => $labels,
    'public'              => true,
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'query_var'           => true,
    'rewrite'             => array(
                              'with_front' => true,
                              'slug'       => 'practical-courses'
                            ),
    'capability_type'     => 'page',
    'hierarchial'         => true,
    'supports'            => array(
                              'title',
                              'editor',
                              'excerpt',
                              'thumbnail',
                              'revisions',
                              'author',
                              'page-attributes',
                              'comments',
                            ),
    'menu_position'       => 20,
    'menu_icon'           => '',
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
  );
```

The register-call:

```
register_post_type('practical-courses',$args);
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your call to register_post_type? And any custom rewrite rules?

Comment: Can we see all of the arguments in $args?

Comment: I've added all the arguments

Comment: Hi - sorry I didn't see your reply as you didn't reference me in yours.  I've pasted your code into functions.php on a test site, created a post, saved my permalink and it just works as expected.  That is, http://localhost/practical-courses/test/ returns a page.